# How to load more than 4GB at once into a memory buffer?

Tags: winapi, readfile

How to load more than 4GB of a file into a memory buffer at once (= using a single WinAPI call)? The WinAPI `ReadFile` method supports only up to 4294967295 bytes.

Note: just to make things clear for people who stumble upon this question during a web search: this is usually a *very* bad idea. We have considered it for a very special scenario but didn't go with it. We are still interested though, on a theoretical level, if it'd been possible and how.

Comment: To make it extra clear for them, you can't use the standard memory allocation functions to allocate a buffer that large.

Comment: I'm a little bit baffled about the downvotes, is there anything I can do to improve the question? Is it bad practice to ask questions which are interesting only from a theoretical standpoint on StackOverflow?

Comment: @HansPassant on a 64bit system, a 64bit process can allocate a buffer larger than 4 GB using standard memory functions

Comment: @D.R. have you considered using a memory mapping via `CreateFileMapping()` and `MapViewOfFile()` instead of using `ReadFile()`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: yes, please note: my question is of theoretical nature only.

Comment: The number of bytes to read you pass to `ReadFile` is a `DWORD`, that is a 32 bit unsigned integer. Therefore: no you can't. But reading such large amounts at a time is rather pointless anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with a single call to a Win32 API function. Call `ReadFile` multiple times, reading blocks no more than 4GB in size until you have read all that needs to be read.

If it helps your desire to make a single function call, wrap up this loop in a function that you define, and call that.

Comment: Well it depends what you mean by at once. It takes time to read the file so it's never "at once" in my understanding of that phrase. More clearer would be to have asked if there was a Win32 API that could read that much with a single call.

Comment: I've updated my question to make it clearer, hope you reconsider your downvote, thanks.

Comment: You don't know who voted. Anyway, you have your answer.